# Service Account key showing up in CLI but not in GCP Console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When executing the command to list keys for a specific SA it indicates there was a key created:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys list --iam-account=service-account@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com --project project-name
```

output example

```
KEY_ID                                    CREATED_AT            EXPIRES_AT           
abc123abc123xyz123xyz123                  2023-04-26T08:00:19Z  2023-05-13T08:00:19Z
```

However when looking at the keys for this service account in the Console there are no keys. How can I validate and confirm what this key is and whether it actually exists or not?

Answer (score 2):

Realised this is a system managed key (owned by Google). I validated this first by adding `--mananged-by user` and the key didn't show up. Then I ran the command with `--managed-by system` and it showed up. I then ran the command with `--format json` to output more verbose data:

```
$ gcloud iam service-accounts keys list --iam-account=service-account@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com --project project-name --format json

[
  {
    "keyAlgorithm": "KEY_ALG_RSA_2048",
    "keyOrigin": "GOOGLE_PROVIDED",
    "keyType": "SYSTEM_MANAGED",
    "name": "projects/project-name/serviceAccounts/service-account@mgcp-1068761-eagleeye-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com/keys/abc123abc123xyz123xyz123",
    "validAfterTime": "2023-04-26T08:00:19Z",
    "validBeforeTime": "2023-05-13T08:00:19Z"
  }
]
```